# issues running a 32 qubit grover's algorithm

Tags: ibm-q-experience, grovers-algorithm

I have a 32 qubit grover's algoritm however whenever I run it on the simulator that IBM offers it always ouputs a probability of 1 on every single result.

Is there a way to run circuits larger then 32 qubits without the "randomness" of a quantum computer? I tried but I got an error saying that the simulator only supports up to 16 qubits.

I also found that whenever the number of quantum gates is larger then 2000 the simulator just comes back with an error, since the grover operator has to be repeated sqrt(n) number of times this is actually a pretty big issue. Anyone have any idea how to circumvent this?